# ¿Cómo interpreta el navegador la función de CSS "url()" con rutas relativas?

Tags: css, url, navegador-web

Supongamos que escribimos en un navegador la petición: "http://ejemplo.com/index.php" y el navegador recibe esa página con un CSS en la cabecera que tiene el atributo:

```
background-image: url(/assets/img/imagen.jpg);
```

¿Como es capaz el navegador de resolver correctamente la ubicación "remota" del archivo imagen.jpg teniendo en cuenta que los CSS se procesan "localmente" en el navegador y que no hemos especificado la url completa en la función url()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las direcciones se procesan usando como base la dirección URL *del archivo que contiene el CSS*. Puede ser un css de otro dominio/servidor, en ese caso las rutas se resuelven usando la ruta relativa o absoluta de dicha pagina:

Ej1: 
Pagina http://ejemplo.com/index.php
Contiene un CSS  http://ejemplo2.com/css/style.css (otro dominio)

- Si dentro del css existe `background-image: url(/assets/img/imagen.jpg)` se resolvera como http://ejemplo2.com/assets/img/imagen.jpg
- Si dentro del css existe `background-image: url(assets/img/imagen.jpg)` se resolvera como http://ejemplo2.com/css/assets/img/imagen.jpg

Ej2:
Pagina http://ejemplo.com/index.php
Contiene un CSS  http://ejemplo.com/css/style.css (o /css/style.css)

- Si dentro del css existe `background-image: url(/assets/img/imagen.jpg)` se resolvera como http://ejemplo.com/assets/img/imagen.jpg
- Si dentro del css existe `background-image: url(assets/img/imagen.jpg)` se resolvera como http://ejemplo.com/css/assets/img/imagen.jpg

Igualmente para los @import, cada URL dentro de las declaraciones de CSS son relativas a la ubicacion del archivo CSS.

Answer (score 2):

En el ejemplo que pones, sí le estás entregando una ruta absoluta, sólo que como no le estás entregando un dominio, asume que es el mismo que el actual:

```
background-image: url(/assets/img/imagen.jpg);
```

Significa:

> buscar la imagen en http://www.midominio.com/assets/img/imagen.jpg

Donde el host (www.midominio.com) es el mismo host desde donde estás viendo la página.

Obviamente si le especificas otro dominio, entonces allá lo buscará:

```
background-image: url(http://www.otrodominio.com/assets/img/imagen.jpg);
```

Y si especificas una ruta relativa:

```
background-image: url(../img/imagen.jpg);
```

Significa:

> buscar el archivo un directorio más arriba del presente archivo CSS, y
>   luego entrando  a la carpeta `img`

Ojo, que usar rutas relativas cuando importas hojas de estilos usando @import implica que las rutas serán relativas al archivo que importa al otro.

Por ejemplo, en un esquema como el siguiente

```
  - css
    - style.css
    - subestilos
      - cabecera.css
  - img
    - logo.png
```

Si en `cabecera.css` quisieras referenciar el logo, le pondrías la ruta relativa desde `cabecera.css`.

```
background-image: url(../../img/logo.png);
```

Pero si en tu página usas solamente `style.css` y éste importa los subestilos haciendo

```
@import subestilos/cabecera.css;
```

Tendrías que cambiar las imágenes para usar la ruta delativa desde `style.css`.

```
background-image: url(../img/logo.png);
```